# Why select statement in GoLang

Tags: go

Am learning `Go` and here in [this example](https://gobyexample.com/select), i can see that `select` statement lets a goroutine wait on multiple communication operations

Do we really need a `select` statement ? My below does the same without `select` statement

```
func runForChannel1(channel1 chan string) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    channel1 <- "Hi Arun ... I am Channel-1"
}

func runForChannel2(channel2 chan string) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    channel2 <- "Hi Arun ... I am Channel-2"
}

func testSelect() {
    channel1 := make(chan string)
    channel2 := make(chan string)

    go runForChannel1(channel1)
    go runForChannel2(channel2)

    chval1, chval2 := <-channel1, <-channel2
    fmt.Println(chval1, chval2)

}

func main() {
    testSelect()
}
```

Without the `select` statment, i was able to wait for both the channels to get their values... Why we would need `Select` statement ? Can someone educate me please ?

Comment: Your code waits for both the channels whereas select waits for either

Comment: Gotchaa !! pretty clear now

Comment: The `context` package documentation has an [interesting example involving a cancellation channel](https://godoc.org/context#example-WithCancel).

Comment: Most basic questions are answered within the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which only takes a few minutes to finish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do we really need a select statement ?

Yes. No user code can select exactly one of several possible channel operations if several are able to execute or none (default) if no case is ready.

(Your code does something completely different.)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a bad idea to create select case in golang.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [answer], then [edit] the post to explain *why* you think it's a bad idea to create select statements in Go-Lang.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33131064)